# Expand header row into multiple child rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Within my SQL database I have a table which represents books of tickets [Books] where the number of tickets within a book can vary.

This is represented by two columns `[Books].[StartNo]` and `[Books].[BookSize]`

What I need to achieve is a select statement that repeats each row in the table [Books] for each ticket in that book with an additional calculated column that displays the ticket number for that row.

So from

```
--------+---------+----------
Book    | StartNo | BookSize 
--------+---------+----------
Book 1  |   1     |    3     
Book 2  |   4     |    4    
Book 3  |  19     |    4
```

to something like this

```
--------+---------+----------+----------
Book    | StartNo | BookSize | TicketNo
--------+---------+----------+----------
Book 1  |   1     |    3     |    1
Book 1  |   1     |    3     |    2
Book 1  |   1     |    3     |    3
Book 2  |   4     |    4     |    4
Book 2  |   4     |    4     |    5
Book 2  |   4     |    4     |    6
Book 2  |   4     |    4     |    7
Book 3  |  19     |    4     |   19
Book 3  |  19     |    4     |   20
Book 3  |  19     |    4     |   21
Book 3  |  19     |    4     |   22
```

I'm just not quite sure where to start.

Comment: It would be great if the solution was compatible with sql server 2005, but I'd settle for 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tally table`

```
WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) --10 * 10 =  100
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) --100 * 10 = 1000
    ,Tally (num) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv2)
    SELECT (num+StartNo-1) as TicketNo, *
    FROM   Tally
           CROSS JOIN Yourtable
    WHERE  num <= booksize
    ORDER  BY book
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
;WITH Counts AS (
    SELECT Max(StartNo + BookSize) AS TotalBookSize
    FROM t
), CTE(Tickets) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Tickets + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Tickets < (SELECT TotalBookSize FROM Counts)
)
SELECT *
FROM t JOIN CTE ON CTE.Tickets BETWEEN t.StartNo AND t.StartNo + t.BookSize - 1
```

Comment: The [Books] table contains around 15k books with each book containing anything from 10 - 25 tickets. Currently when I put the CTE in to practice I get a max recursion error. I can get It to work by setting "option (maxrecursion 0)" but it is slowed considerably. I've tried to play around with the CTE to optimize it but haven't come up with anything yet... will let you know if I do.

Answer (score 0):

you need a list of numbers and join it with the books table

```
select b.*, number
from Books b
join master.dbo.spt_values v on v.number between b.StartNo AND b.StartNo+b.BookSize-1
```