# Repeat row number of times based on column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I have table which looks like this:

```
| name |  start_date   |  duration_day|
========================================
|   A  |  2015-01-01   |       3      |
|   B  |  2015-01-02   |       2      |
```

And now I want to get an output like so:

```
   | name |     date   |
   =====================
   |  A   | 2015-01-01 |
   |  A   | 2015-01-02 |
   |  A   | 2015-01-03 |
   |  B   | 2015-01-02 |
   |  B   | 2015-01-03 |
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I expand out a row into multiple row result set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385574/how-can-i-expand-out-a-row-into-multiple-row-result-set)

Comment: @Bulat Not really. Not PG and there are also better solutions in PG than in that answer.

Comment: @Patrick, Thanks Patrick for updating my question

Comment: example of a generic solution using a dynamic tally table can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402329/expand-header-row-into-multiple-child-rows but for PG using generate_series is tidy

Comment: Can `duration_day ` be `NULL` or `0` and how shall that affect the result? And *always* provide your version of Postgres, please. `LATERAL` joins were introduced with pg 9.3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19127999/939860

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Duplicate (repeat) rows in sql query result](//stackoverflow.com/q/35293084/90527)", "[SQL: Repeat a result row multiple times, and number the rows](//stackoverflow.com/q/10423767/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from [Abelisto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35951622/3304426), you can generate a series from the `duration_day` value with the [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) [table function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) in the row source list. The function uses the `duration_day` value from `my_table` through an implicit [lateral join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL).

```
SELECT name, start_date + n AS date
FROM my_table, generate_series(0, duration_day - 1) AS x(n);
```

Comment: To stop discussing about `generate_series()` usage [here is solution without it](http://pastebin.com/1Vavy8yT) :)

Comment: @Abelisto Yeah. Why do it easy when there is a hard way? {;-)

Comment: I agree with you.  I don't like `generate_series()` anywhere except the `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "You do not like kittens? You just don't know how to cook them!" Just a joke.

Comment: Could you tell to why generate_series in select is bad?

Comment: @JaehyunShin `generate_series()` is a so-called table function (click on the link in my answer): "Table functions are functions that produce a set of rows, made up of either base data types (scalar types) or composite data types (table rows). They are used like a table, view, or subquery in the FROM clause of a query." There are conditions where the use of table functions in select lists lead to unpredictable results, in particular when multiple table functions are used.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  name, 
  start_date + generate_series(0, duration_day - 1)
from
  your_table;
```

Comment: C'mon! `generate_series()` in a select list is bad practice. You can do better than that!